# How to write file docker-compose and dockerfie for Django connect Kong api

Tags: python, django, docker, api, kong

I'm doing a graduation project, and I'm about to put my project up to the server, but I'm having trouble with `docker-compose.yml` and `Dockerfile` files, could you please advise me where I should fix it?

***How to fix this error?***
nginx: [error] init_by_lua error: /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/kong/cmd/utils/migrations.lua:16: Database needs bootstrapping or is older than Kong 1.0.
To start a new installation from scratch, run 'kong migrations bootstrap'.
To migrate from a version older than 1.0, migrated to Kong 1.5.0 first.
If you still have 'apis' entities, you can convert them to Routes and Services
using the 'kong migrations migrate-apis' command in Kong 1.5.0.
stack traceback:
[C]: in function 'error'
/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/kong/cmd/utils/migrations.lua:16: in function 'check_state'
/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/kong/init.lua:562: in function 'init'
init_by_lua:3: in main chunk

dockerfile files

```bash
FROM python:3.10
 
WORKDIR /app
 
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
 
EXPOSE 8000
CMD ["python3", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]
```

docker-compose files

```yaml
version: '3.9'
services:
  kong-database:
    image: postgres:latest
    container_name: kong-database
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 15432:5432
    networks:
      - default
    volumes:
      - db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=kong
      - POSTGRES_USER=kong
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=kong

  kong:
    image: kong:latest
    container_name: kong
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 18000:8000
      - 18443:8443
      - 127.0.0.1:8001:8001
      - 18444:8444
    links:
      - kong-database:kong-database
    networks:
      - default
    environment:
      - LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8
      - LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
      - KONG_DATABASE=postgres
      - KONG_PG_HOST=kong-database
      - KONG_PG_USER=kong
      - KONG_PG_PASSWORD=kong
      - KONG_CASSANDRA_CONTACT_POINTS=kong-database
      - KONG_PROXY_ACCESS_LOG=/dev/stdout
      - KONG_ADMIN_ACCESS_LOG=/dev/stdout
      - KONG_PROXY_ERROR_LOG=/dev/stderr
      - KONG_ADMIN_ERROR_LOG=/dev/stderr
      - KONG_ADMIN_LISTEN=0.0.0.0:18001, 0.0.0.0:18444 ssl
    
  konga:
    image: pantsel/konga
    container_name: kong-konga
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 1337:1337
    networks:
      - default
    volumes:
      - data:/app/kongadata
    links:
      - kong:kong
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=production

networks:
  default:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  db:
    driver: local
  data:
    driver: local
```

setting.py

```py
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'kong',
        'USER': 'kong',
        'PASSWORD': 'kong',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '15432',
    }
}
```

Comment: When you say "it doesn't always work", what does happen?  Is the application also running in a container?  Is there any application code that would help demonstrate the problem further?

Comment: As David stated, posting the error message is better for us to help you. For the Kong part, you're missing the migrations part of Kong installation. hence, Kong cannot correctly work with a database that hasn't been bootstrapping. Additionally, the newer Kong version is now operates in "free mode", so you can use UI without using Konga (kong/kong-gateway image on DockerHub).

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm a newbie in Docker. I have corrected my question.

Answer (score 0):

Consider running required migration process before launching pythong? E.g.

```
CMD ["kong", "migrations bootstrap && python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"]
```

Answer (score 0):

> Database needs bootstrapping or is older than Kong 1.0. To start a new installation from scratch, run 'kong migrations bootstrap'. To migrate from a version older than 1.0, migrated to Kong 1.5.0 first. If you still have 'apis' entities, you can convert them to Routes and Services using the 'kong migrations migrate-apis' command in Kong 1.5.0.

The error comes from Kong not being able to use the database provided. when you bringing up kong there need to be an additional step of [`migrations/bootstrap`](https://docs.konghq.com/gateway/latest/install/docker/#prepare-the-database) to prepare the database to be used by Kong.

Since you are using Docker Compose to bring the whole environment up, adding an additional container to do the migration first should be sufficient:

```
kong-migrations:
    container_name: kong-migrations
    image: kong:latest
    environment:
      - KONG_DATABASE=postgres
      - KONG_PG_HOST=kong-database
      - KONG_PG_USER=kong
      - KONG_PG_PASSWORD=kong
      - KONG_PASSWORD=kong
    networks:
      - default
    command: kong migrations bootstrap
    depends_on:
      - kong-database
```

Since you are mounting data volume from/to Kong database, the first run might not work since Kong might start before the migrations finish. If that's the case, simply wait for Kong to restart automatically and it should work.